# how to upload file on server in node js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, multer

could you please tell me how to upload the file on some directory current example (`uploads` folder) .Here is my server side code

```
app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
  console.log('abcc')
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({error_code: 1, err_desc: err});
            return;
        }
        res.json({error_code: 0, err_desc: null});
    });
});
```

**full code node js**
https://repl.it/repls/LustrousCharmingCommunication

I used this server and hit the service using client and **upload only attached file**

here is my request **client code**
https://jsbin.com/luwezirive/edit?html,js,output

```
 $(function () {
        $('.submit').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            if ($('#fileId').val().length === 0) {
                alert('please insert file')
            } else {
                var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

                // Create an FormData object
                var data = new FormData(form);
              console.log('fffff')
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://lustrouscharmingcommunication--five-nine.repl.co/upload',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processData: false, // Don't process the files
                    contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                      console.log('succsss'); 
                      if (typeof data.error === 'undefined') {
                            // Success so call function to process the form
                        }
                        else {
                            // Handle errors here
                            console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        // Handle errors here
                        console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
                        // STOP LOADING SPINNER
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    })
```

I am getting success but file is not uploaded why ?

upload method

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var datetimestamp = Date.now();
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 1])
    }
});
var upload = multer({ //multer settings
    storage: storage
}).single('file');
```

any update ?

Comment: What's your `upload()` method?

Comment: The first problem that I can see is `var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];`. Selecting element with `Id` doesn't give you an array. So, change it to `var form = $('#fileUploadForm');`

Comment: @GeorgeBailey No, this isn't an array, this is a jQuery object, and accessing to index 0 will give you the DOM object that corresponding to the first element in the set. This isn't an error :-)

Comment: @GeorgeBailey It's equals to `var form = document.getElementById('fileUploadForm');` or to `var form = document.querySelector('#fileUploadForm');`.

Comment: Please display us your `upload()` method!

Comment: @ChayimFriedman check the source code url that he has put in the page

Comment: please check my source url and  updates questoion

Comment: @any body have idea

Comment: Can you try `console.log(req.file)` to see if you have any file on the request ?

Comment: ok I am able to save file but i am some query please anser here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51873375/how-to-hit-post-request-so-that-uploaded-file-save-on-some-location?noredirect=1#comment90700071_51873375

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using `multer`. https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Example taken from the documentation:

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

var app = express()

app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

Comment: please check my Quesion

Comment: please remove your anser ..please tell me my mistake