# how to hit post request so that uploaded file save on some location

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am trying to upload like file using `node js` using `multer` node plugin.
server.js code
**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// use of body parser

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var datetimestamp = Date.now();
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length - 1])
    }
});
var upload = multer({ //multer settings
    storage: storage
}).single('file');


app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({error_code: 1, err_desc: err});
            return;
        }
        res.json({error_code: 0, err_desc: null});
    });
});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App is listening to ${PORT}`);
})
```

code is also present here https://repl.it/repls/LustrousCharmingCommunication

here is on client side I am using jquery

**client code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="fileUploadForm">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="fileId"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" class="submit">
    label <input type="text" placeholder="enter first name"/>
</form>
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
</body>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.submit').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            if ($('#fileId').val().length === 0) {
                alert('please insert file')
            } else {
                var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

                // Create an FormData object
                var data = new FormData(form);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/upload',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    cache: false,
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processData: false, // Don't process the files
                    contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if (typeof data.error === 'undefined') {
                            // Success so call function to process the form
                        }
                        else {
                            // Handle errors here
                            console.log('ERRORS: ' + data.error);
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        // Handle errors here
                        console.log('ERRORS: ' + textStatus);
                        // STOP LOADING SPINNER
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    })
</script>
</html>
```

code is also  present here

https://jsbin.com/luwezirive/edit?html,js,output

why file is not uploaded in `uploads` folder ? I want to upload the attached file on button click

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @BalaAbhinav I am not getting error .but i am confused why I am sending whole formdata .istead of sending only attached file

Comment: i am able to save filed or upload file on `uploads` folder .but I am confuse why I am sending formdata

Comment: Because to send files to the server, you either have to send it as multipart/form-data or convert the file into base64 URI string and send it as json and decode it in the server which is not recommended. FormData is the way to upload files to your backend.

Comment: I am fine  with using formData , but in my request will `first name` or input field values present  in forms go as to request .in present example `name` input field will go ?

Comment: I am confuse in these `two` lines  var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

                // Create an FormData object
                var data = new FormData(form);

Comment: what is value of `data` here ..data contain `attached file` only ? or it contain attached file with forms field ? and how server save only `file` where other data is gone

Comment: Data contains file with form fields

Comment: You can access other data in your server in the request body. You can access it in your req variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178121/discussion-between-user944513-and-bala-abhinav).

Comment: Hi
there
I have one last question
how i will print all form data value of server
req.body ?